# Windows 7 license transfer

Tags: windows-7, license, license-key

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When reinstalling Windows 7, does the language, version, architecture (64-bit or 32-bit) or source (OEM, retail, or MSDN) matter?](https://superuser.com/questions/303136/when-reinstalling-windows-7-does-the-language-version-architecture-64-bit-or)

I bought Windows 7 Home Basic on 11-12-2009 and installed on my HP TX1000 tablet laptop.

Today it crashed, I have another Acer Atom laptop I want to shift it (the license) to this.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6):

Install on the new laptop and activate.  If the activation fails, contact Microsoft at the phone number that will be displayed and explain the situation.

Comment: +1 As long as you have a full retail copy of Win7 then this is exactly what you do, and I have done it myself when I've upgraded.  As DaveM says you may have to phone a number but I believe that the majority of that call is leading up to the question "How many machines is this installed on?"  which should only ever be 1 for a single user copy of Win7.  I'd format the old machine to make sure you don't have any licensing issues.